# Python NetworkX Increase circular graph size

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is it possible to increase the size of graphs generated with networkx? Currently, it always outputs 800x600.

How can I output a graph with a larger radius. Does it depend on my display size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example page from NetworkX show that case:

http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/circular_tree.html

These lines do square image 800x800px:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.savefig('circular_tree.png')
```